# Need to cast element of NSArray to Swift class

Tags: ios, objective-c, xcode, swift, unit-testing

I have an NSArray comprising two different classes, one of which is in Swift (ClassS) and the other in Objective-C (ClassO). Here's an example of what it may look like inside:

`NSArray *allObjects=@[classOObject,classSObject,classOObject,classSObject,etc.];`

In a Swift unit testing file, I'm looping through this array and doing some testing on the ClassS objects only.

```
for thisObject in allObjects{
  if thisObject is ClassS{
    // do stuff
  }
}
```

**The `thisObject is ClassS` expression always evaluates false; why is this happening?** If I replace the if statement with `if thisObject is ClassO`, then it works just fine at detecting ClassO objects.

Some other points that may or may not be relevant:

- In XCode's Variables View, the `thisObject`'s class is ClassO_ClassO_ * for the ClassO objects, but as MyApp.ClassS_ClassS_ * for the ClassS objects.
- In the Variables View, the class name of the array is `[AnyObject]!`
- Both ClassS and ClassO inherit from the same Objective C superclass, itself a subclass of `NSManagedObject`.
- MyAppTests-Bridging-Header.h imports both ClassO.h and the common superclass to ClassO.h and ClassS.h
- Replacing `if thisObject is ClassS` with `if let castedObject = thisObject as? ClassS` or `thisObject.isKindOfClass(ClassS)` has no effect

Thanks for reading, any ideas would be fantastic.

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried to use `if let` ?

```
for thisObject in allObjects{
  if let thisObject = thisObject as? ClassS {
    // do stuff
  } else if let thisObject = thisObject as? ClassO {
    // do stuff
  } else {

  }
}
```

Comment: Thanks for the reply. Just tried it, and no luck unfortunately.

Answer (score 0):

You can use `isKindOfClass`:

```
class One {

}

class Two {

}

let arr = NSArray(objects: One(), Two())

for obj in arr {
    if obj.isKindOfClass(One) {
        println("one")
    } else if obj.isKindOfClass(Two) {
        println("two")
    }
}
```

Comment: Thanks for the reply, much appreciated. If I do this, how would I then call class-specific methods on obj without compiler errors?

Comment: Well, I'm afraid it's an entirely different question, isn't it?

Comment: Just tested this, and besides the problem calling some class-specific methods, the ClassS methods still don't pass the `isKindOfClass(ClassS)` test, oddly.

Comment: Weird indeed. I tried in a Playground and it was [ok](https://www.evernote.com/l/AOxR8JEZozZAf5dyUCVHoOroTJJMrn9thYwB/image.png).

Comment: Yes, I think it has something to do with the other details: one class in Swift, the other is Objective-C, both are subclasses of `NSManagedObject` through their parent class, the testing is done in Unit Testing, etc.